# How to encode/decode a dictionary with Codable values for storage in UserDefaults?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, codable, swift5, swift-dictionary, nsarchiving

I am trying to store a dictionary of company names (string) mapped to Company objects (from a struct Company) in iOS UserDefaults. I have created the Company struct and made it conform to Codable. I have one example a friend helped me with in my project where we created a class Account and stored it in UserDefaults by making a Defaults struct (will include example code). I have read in the swift docs that dictionaries conform to Codable and in order to stay Codable, must contain Codable objects. That is why I made struct Company conform to Codable.

I have created a struct for Company that conforms to Codable. I have tried using model code to create a new struct CompanyDefaults to handle the getting and setting of the Company dictionary from/to UserDefaults. I feel I have some beginner misconceptions about what needs to happen and about how it should be implemented (with good design in mind).

The dictionary I wish to store looks like `[String:Company]`
where company name will be String and a Company object for Company

I used conform to Codable as I did some research and it seemed like a newer method for completing similar tasks.

Company struct

```
struct Company: Codable {
    var name:String?
    var initials:String? = nil
    var logoURL:URL? = nil
    var brandColor:String? = nil // Change to UIColor

    enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case initials = "initials"
        case logoURL = "logoURL"
        case brandColor = "brandColor"
    }

    init(name:String?, initials:String?, logoURL:URL?, brandColor:String?) {
        self.name = name
        self.initials = initials
        self.logoURL = logoURL
        self.brandColor = brandColor
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        initials = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .initials)
        logoURL = try values.decode(URL.self, forKey: .logoURL)
        brandColor = try values.decode(String.self, forKey:   .brandColor)

    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(initials, forKey: .initials)
        try container.encode(logoURL, forKey: .logoURL)
        try container.encode(brandColor, forKey: .brandColor)
    }

}
```

Defaults struct to control storage

```
struct CompanyDefaults {

    static private let companiesKey = "companiesKey"

    static var companies: [String:Company] = {

        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: companiesKey) else { return [:] }
        let companies = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data) as? [String : Company] ?? [:]
        return companies!
        }() {
        didSet {
            guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: companies, requiringSecureCoding: false) else {
                return
            }

            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: companiesKey)
        }
    }
}
```

I should be able to reference the stored dictionary throughout my code like `CompanyDefaults.companies.count`

For reference, a friend helped me do a similar task for an array of Account classes stored in user defaults. The code that works perfectly for that is below. The reason I tried a different way is that I had a different data structure (dictionary) and made the decision to use structs.

```
class Account: NSObject, NSCoding {

    let service: String
    var username: String
    var password: String

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(service)
        aCoder.encode(username)
        aCoder.encode(password)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        guard let service = aDecoder.decodeObject() as? String,
        var username = aDecoder.decodeObject() as? String,
        var password = aDecoder.decodeObject() as? String else {
            return nil
        }

        self.service = service
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    }

    init(service: String, username: String, password: String) {
        self.service = service
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
    }

}
```

```
struct Defaults {

    static private let accountsKey = "accountsKey"

    static var accounts: [Account] = {

        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: accountsKey) else { return [] }

        let accounts = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [Account] ?? []
        return accounts

        }() {
        didSet {
            guard let data = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: accounts, requiringSecureCoding: false) else {
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: accountsKey)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `NSCoding` and `Codable`. The former requires a sub**class** of `NSObject`, the latter can encode the structs and classes directly with `JSONEncoder` or `ProperListEncoder` without any `Keyedarchiver` which also belongs to `NSCoding`.

Your struct can be reduced to

```
struct Company: Codable {
    var name : String
    var initials : String
    var logoURL : URL?
    var brandColor : String?
}
```

That's all, the CodingKeys and the other methods are synthesized. I would at least declare `name` and `initials` as non-optional.

To read and save the data is pretty straightforward. The corresponding `CompanyDefaults` struct is

```
struct CompanyDefaults {

    static private let companiesKey = "companiesKey"

    static var companies: [String:Company] = {

        guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: companiesKey) else { return [:] }
        return try? JSONDecoder.decode([String:Company].self, from: data) ?? [:]
        }() {
        didSet {
            guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(companies) else { return }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: companiesKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly! I tried to do my due diligence researching Codable and NSCoding, but I obviously have doubts. Why does NSCoding require a subclass while Codable is more flexible (allows for struct or class implementation, right?) ? And more importantly, why did we not have to manually encode the ```Company``` type in the dictionary? Does Codable do something behind the scenes where it encode the dictionary contents' types, and the encodes the entire object?

Comment: `Codable` is *Swift only*. The protocol extension provides a lot of (synthesized) boilerplate code by default. `NSCoding` exists for a long time in the Objective-C runtime, that's the reason why a `NSObject` subclass is required.